# Validate File Selection while uploading

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Is there anyway that i can check whether any file is selected or not ? I am working on user registration and i need to check whether the user selects his profile picture or not ? If he doesn't select a picture then i will display an error message.

Comment: Just a thought, I do believe that this means that you have to upload the whole file to the server, since java will be on the server side. If it is just a few profile pictures at the time it doesn't really matter, but with a large site your server would do a lot of work which could be resolved with for example javascript :)

Comment: I know that. But in this case, I need to validate at the server end.. Is there any way around ?

Comment: It is possible, on the server side you can check the data of the uploaded file. If it is null or empty than it is not a valid picture :) (You could also try to load it as an image to see that it is a real image file and not text etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you have html like

```
<input id="profile_pic" type="file" />
```

You can use javascript to check if the value is null, before submitting

```
document.getElementById("profile_pic").value
```

Comment: i want to check within java code... isn't that possible .. ? What i tried was if the provided id has null value.. But in java .. it didn't work !

Comment: In java, you can check if file.getInputStream is null. There is a sample example here http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glraq.html

Comment: @RoshanShahukhal why you want to do with java code?The problem will be first client send all the information to server,In server you will check if file is empty or not.If empty then again send back to client. Unnecessary going to server for validation.Better validate everything in client side it self

Comment: javascript can be disabled in the browsers. And thus, it wouldn't be the safest validation tool. Would it be ?

Comment: Look man.. technically you are right. In fact you should have validation in both UI as well as server. But remember the fact, that if JS is blocked in the browser, most of the websites will not run at all...